# Compiler warning about async shouldn't happen

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, compiler-warnings

So the following code triggers the compiler warning:

"*Async function without await operator will run synchronously*"

```
    public async Task UpsertMariaDb()
    {
        IEnumerable<Task> insertTasks = InsertSomethingDb();
        IEnumerable<Task> updateTasks = UpdateSomethingDb();

        Task.WaitAll(insertTasks.ToArray());
        Task.WaitAll(updateTasks.ToArray());
    }
```

My question is the following, is there something very basic I don't understand about async/await or is this just a compiler warning bug because I haven't put an explicit "*await*"

Comment: You should use the `await` keyword in a method marked as `async`. If you are just calling `Task.Wait...` you don't need to mark the method as `async`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `await Task.WhenAll()` (asynchronous) instead of `Task.WaitAll()` (synchronous)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Task.WaitAll` blocks the current thread, so the warning is correct - you try to implement an async method, but it is not async as there is nothing being awaited.

You probably meant to do:

```
public async Task UpsertMariaDb()
{
    IEnumerable<Task> insertTasks = InsertSomethingDb();
    IEnumerable<Task> updateTasks = UpdateSomethingDb();

    await Task.WhenAll(insertTasks);
    await Task.WhenAll(updateTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for turning my comment into an actual answer. :)

Comment: Sorry your comment came up when I already started typing my answer so I thought I should continue anyways ;)

Comment: You can remove the `.ToArray()`, it is superfluous. `Task.WhenAll` has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @JohnathanBarclay, I edited my post accordingly ;)